# Prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2{a_n}}{(a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n)^{2}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

Prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2{a_n}}{(a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n)^{2}}$  converges given $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n}$ convereges, $\forall a_n > 0$

This is a question that a friend of mine has studied throughout the last semester and failed to solve. I think he would like to figure out this question but needs some hints.

Comment: Answered e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200514/42969 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2543985/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E2%7Ba_n%7D%7D%7B(a_1%20%2B%20a_2%20%2B%20%5Cdots%20%2B%20a_n)%5E%7B2%7D%7D%24)

Answer (score 2):

Define $B_n = \dfrac{n^2a_n}{S^2_n}, S_n =\sum_{k=1}^n a_k, R_n= \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{a_k}$. By Cauchy inequality twice: $S_n \ge \dfrac{n^2}{R_n}$. So $R_n  \ge \dfrac{n^2}{S_n}$. Thus $B_n = \dfrac{n^2}{S_n}\cdot \dfrac{a_n}{S_n}\le \dfrac{a_n}{S_n}\cdot R_n\le R_n$. Thus by comparison test, $\sum B_n$ converges !

Comment: How do you get $B_n \le \dfrac{a_n}{S_n}\cdot R_n$?

Comment: Incorrect argument.

Comment: In fact $B_n$ should be $\le 25R_n$

Comment: $B_n\leq R_n$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} R_n<\infty$ are true. But, $\sum R_n$ may not converge. Thus, your argument by comparison test is incorrect.